# Martingale convergence theorem with alternative assumptions

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, almost-everywhere

Has anyone a source (book, paper, ...) containing a proof of the following theorem ?

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ a sequence of nonnegative random variables adapted to a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$, and satisfying the conditions
(i) $E(X_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F}_n)\geq X_n$ almost sure for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$
(ii) $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}E(X_n\mid\mathcal{F}_0)<\infty$ almost sure.
Then $X_n$ conveges almost sure to a finite random variable $X_\infty$

Comment: Maybe you could multiply by minus 1 and then make reference to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems to prove it for $(-X_n)_{n\inN}$ then argue that your statement holds.

Comment: But how does (ii) imply $sup_{n} E(X_n\mid\mathcal{F} _0) <\infty?$ I do not know how to deal with the conditional boundedness...

Comment: multiplying by -1 swops the 'smaller than' with a 'bigger than' sign and then (ii) is just the boundedness of the negative part according to the Wiki article, just expresses a bit differently. In other words, your $-X_n$ corresponds to the $X_n$ in the Wiki article. The proof there thus also proves your statement.

Comment: I cant use the "normal" martingaleconvergence theorem, since $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}E(X)<\infty $ is not given by assumption...

Comment: by "normal" you mean the theorem in the Wiki article? I don't see why the conditions there wouldn't apply to your statement

Comment: Yes, the "statement for discrete-time martingale" as it is called in wiki needs the assumtion  $sup_{n>1}E(X_n)<\infty$ to be fulfilled, in the theorem that I stated above we only have $sup_{n>1}E(X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_0)<\infty$ is given.

Comment: good observation! I think Wiki omits the conditioning because it is implied there. But it's tricky because in Wiki the sequence starts at time 1 and then F_0 is usually meant to be the trivial sigma algebra {empty set, Omega}. Your sequence starts at time 0 and moreover $X_0$ is measurable wrt F_0. So this is different. I am also not sure if applying the law of conditional expectation helps (maybe the conditional expectation is not integrable? If this is indeed possible?). But is it possible that what is meant is "X_n \mid F_0 converges almost surely... "?